# Limit justified by monotonicity of 2 sides

Tags: probability, limits

P. 40 of Probability with Martingales by Williams reads:

$P(\bigcap\limits_{n \geq m}E_n^c) = \prod\limits_{n \geq m}(1-p_n)$

"this equation being true if the condition $\{n \geq m\}$ is replaced by condition $\{r \geq n \geq m\}$, because of independence, and the limit as $r \uparrow \infty $ being *justified by the monotonicity of the 2 sides*" (emphasis is mine).

What is the reasoning behind the justification of taking the limit as $r \uparrow \infty $? Is it using a theorem from real analysis?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [monotone convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem)?

Comment: So that would imply 'justifying the limit' means justifying why the limit exists (on both sides)? That would make sense! I interpreted 'justifying the limit' as justifying why the equality holds in the limit.

Comment: It lacks some context. Usually when an equality depending on some parameter holds, it still holds when taking limit on both sides. Then theorems like monotone convergences help put the limit inside $P$

Answer (score 0):

We usually first define independence for a finite collection of events, then saying that an arbitrary collection of events is independent if each finite sub-collection is independent. So all the information we have is on finite sets of independent events, and we then use the definition. Thant's the justification of the reduction to finite families.

Then we take the limit in order compute the probability of the countable intersection.